# How can I create a function that removes an item from one QTreeWidget and adds it to another?

Tags: c++, qt

I've written code that is supposed to move items between two QTreeWidgets, treeAvailable and treeSelected. The trees are single column and contain QStrings. I assumed the code below would work, but I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't.

```
DataPlaneEditor::DataPlaneEditor(QWidget* parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DataPlaneEditor)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushAdd, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DataPlaneEditor::addButton);
    connect(ui->pushRemove, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DataPlaneEditor::removeButton);
    connect(ui->treeAvailable, &QTreeWidget::doubleClicked, this, &DataPlaneEditor::addButton);
    connect(ui->treeSelected, &QTreeWidget::doubleClicked, this, &DataPlaneEditor::removeButton);
}

void DataPlaneEditor::addButton()
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* chosenData = ui->treeAvailable->currentItem();
    if (!chosenData) return;
    ui->treeAvailable->insertTopLevelItem(0, chosenData);
    ui->treeSelected->removeItemWidget(chosenData, 0);
}

void DataPlaneEditor::removeButton()
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* chosenData = ui->treeSelected->currentItem();
    if (!chosenData) return;
    ui->treeAvailable->insertTopLevelItem(0, chosenData);
    ui->treeSelected->removeItemWidget(chosenData, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QTreeWidget::removeItemWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#removeItemWidget) removes the widget associated with a `QTreeWidgetItem`, not the item itself. For removing the items themselves, look at [QTreeWidget::takeTopLevelItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#takeTopLevelItem) and [QTreeWidgetItem::takeChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#takeChild).